# Access Thumbnails for PDF Sheets in Plan Folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to retrieve thumbnails of individual pdf sheets in plan folder. I have unsuccessfully tried various base64 encoded urns. Passing the design urn of a model file gets the thumbnails successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to retrieve from a server-side, open the manifest `GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/:urn/manifest` and recursively search for `role:2d`, which should give you the sheets on the model, then search for children nodes with `role:thumbnail`, which should give something like the following:

```
{
    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:scfs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcYQlY1YXo1M3c/output/Resource/Sheet/A102 - Plans 382617/dwfx/A102 - Plans1.png",
    "role": "thumbnail",
    "mime": "image/png",
    "guid": "94a13396-cab7-17d9-43df-511de85acd16",
    "type": "resource",
    "resolution": [
        100,
        100
    ],
    "status": "success"
}
```

Using the `urn`, call `GET /derivativeservice/v2/derivatives/{{URN from above}}`

Comment: Hi Augusto, thanks for your response. I'm trying to access thumbnails for PDF sets uploaded to the Plans folder. The above solution works great for sheets that were part of the design file (revit sheets in a revit model) but doesn't seem to work for PDF sets. I guess I'm missing the "design urn" for a PDF set.

Comment: the same approach worked just fine, you just need to focus on PNG with names 100.png/200.png/400.png as there are other PNGs there... if still not working, are you able to share a small PDF so I can try from here? you can send it to forge.help at autodesk.com

Comment: I just emailed you a sample PDF.